# Setting vim spelllang for Italian

Tags: vimrc, neovim, spell-checking

I need to enable the spelllang of vim for Italian as well, but I can't understand how to tell vim to check for Italian words as well.

This is what I have in my init.vim, if it can help you:

[image]

I tried to add "it", "it_IT", but neither of these two works. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works for me. All I need to do is use `:set spelllang+=it` (to spell *both* English and Italian), Vim offers to download the spelling dictionaries for Italian, installs them in place and stops marking valid Italian words.

```
:set spelllang+=it
Cannot find spell file for "it" in utf-8
Do you want me to try downloading it?
(Y)es [N]o:
```

And so on...

I'm on Vim, not NeoVim, but I don't think that should make a difference... Downloading the files needed for an additional language is supported through the `plugin/spellfile.vim` script. Check out the output of `:scriptnames` and make sure it was loaded while Vim was started. If it wasn't, that might be part of the issue.

```
:filter /spell/ scriptnames
 26: .../plugin/spellfile.vim
 55: .../autoload/spellfile.vim
```

Comment: @Ben good catch, thanks! Fixed now.